# Where to put the Object info node..?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Hi I'm trying to restrict the geo shape to "Black" logo. I followed a youtube tutorial for the geo node but I want to change the cube shape into "Black" logo. Where should I put the object info node???

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do it is to launch a ray cast from  front and back of the logo, so that we can hit the object's volume. Here is the example with 3D noise texture, just for clarity:

[image]

The direction of the ray cast is important, you have to run it from "front" side.